# How to insert object into an object x amount of times?

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have this object:

```
const items = {
  0: {
    property: 'test',
  },
};
```

I want to create 8 objects inside of `item`, so I tried this:

```
const items = {
  0: {
    property: 'test',
  },
};

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  console.log(items[i]);
}
```

But that just logs `undefined` 8 times. Any ideas on how I can log something like this?

```
Object {
  0: Object {
    property: "test"
  },
  1: Object {
    property: "test"
  },
  2: Object {
    property: "test"
  },
  3: Object {
    property: "test"
  },
  4: Object {
    property: "test"
  },
  {...}
}
```

Comment: `console.log(items[i]);` shows current content, does not create it - also, if `items` will always have objects with keys `0 ... n` with no gaps ... perhaps `items` should be an "Array" - but only you can decide that

Comment: What is your purpose of having objects within objects?

Answer (score 2):

This is how to do it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  items[i] = {'property': 'test'}
}
```

Then check it out:

```
console.log(items)
```